# Error: Truffle Box at URL https://github.com/truffle-box/bare-box.git doesn't exist. Even after updating truffle

Tags: truffle

I am getting the *Error: Truffle Box at URL https://github.com/truffle-box/bare-box.git doesn't exist. If you believe this is an error, please contact Truffle support.* Even after updating of truffle to 5.1.49.[image]

Comment: @Moosy Do you want to create a Truffle project directory with that?

Comment: Yes I want to create a Truffle project dir

Comment: @Moody I just tried with truffle 5.1.48, node 12.19 and it works. Is your connection behind a proxy? Perhaps it was a temporary network connection issue. Try again if that works or report it to the Truffle project on github.

Answer (score 0):

You used this URL to get Truffle boxes for a project. There is another method to get them. Moreover, because you mentioned that you want to create a Truffle project i provide this answer to you. However, i think this URL doesn't create a directory. Anyways, you can follow this answer to create it perfectly.

1. In terminal ,go to your folder or directory you want the project be created there.
2. Enter the command `mkdir projectName`. This creates the project directory.
3. Enter the command `cd projectName` to go in the project directory.
4. Now, you need to have Truffle boxes. Get them by entering `truffle unbox pet-shop` .

By this way, now you have a directory with all required boxes and tools. There are some contracts in `contracts` folder in the updated project directory that you should replace them with your own contract. And there are some migration js files in `migratoins` folder that you should replace or set them with your required cases. Also, you can use [Truffle document](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/creating-a-project) to more and better information.

You should always pay attention to the fact that Truffle boxes are not digitally signed that makes a security warning or error. So, a related error maybe emerges.In this case, you should fix it in your OS.

Good Luck

Comment: @Moody I hope this answer eliminates your problem. Please tell me the result. Thanks

Comment: @Moody Could you create the directory successfully by this guide?